# Store data according to URL in a Row[PHP]

Tags: php, url

i need help i want to write a code which will detect a kind of url which has no sub dir, only  like just http://site.com/ and in its other corresponding row of the table named as "Confirmed" it should write 1 or something else .But when only the site URL is with no sub dir .

Comment: you can do that using regex patterns

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `parse_url` function? You can check details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

When executed:

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

it returns an array with all the URL elements split into the following:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Then for your case, you should check if the **path** element of the array returned is set or not empty.

Comment: Thanks for your effort brother but .. its not what i meant i suppose i meant that the urls without any subdir should get "1" in the Confirmed column of the row ..